# Mpeg2 decode on a webcam?

Tags: skype, streaming, webcam, mpeg2

I've got a situation here. I'm trying to use a camera hooked up to a capture card as a webcam, however the capture card stream is MPEG2 encoded. Which basically means, since no webcam-using programs actually are able to decode MPEG2 streams (CL-Eye Test seems to be the only working program) I can't use this for things such as, e.g. Skype/XSplit.

Is it possible, in any way, to somehow run the capture card stream through a MPEG2 decoder, into a virtual webcam or something? Thanks. This is on Windows 7 x64.

EDIT: The capture card is a Dell UW121, which is analog. I've connected a Sony camcorder via component, and it seems that the capture card basically streams as opposed to decoding it. The CL-Eye Test program has a MPEG2 decoder built in, which is why it is able to render the input.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the info in.

Comment: ahh, so if it is analog then it is being encoded to some digital format (mpeg2) in the "hardware" or via the computer in "software". Back in XP, I was able to just call up the "capture device" into the same places they asked for a webcam device, worked for 2 programs, the stream was mpeg 1or2?  and it just worked, i was sort of surprised.  I even passed the "Tv" signal to them.  just testing for fun.

Comment: With "graphedit" and other similar, they would software route the stream, to another program , filter, input,output pins etc. Much of it is built into windows and the Direct stuff in windows. search term "graphedit pin video audio"  not being a developer i dont get far with that without explicit instructions, and it had issues.